# How to access /var/www/html folder from ubuntu user through SFTP

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, sftp

I messed up with some permission level on `/var/www/` and `/var/www/html/`folders by running some random commands through putty.

Initially I want to add or edit some files in `/var/www/html/` and I executed some commands which give me the permission to add or edit files through SFTP. But it causes a problem and I was unable to update or create any files through webserver `apache`.

After then I executed some random commands which gives `apache` to view and edit files under `/var/www/html/` but I m not not able to view files from SFTP.

I have attached some screenshot of folder permission

My Configurtion

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Provider: AWS
FTP Username: ubuntu
```

I logged in to SFTP through PPK files

Now I want to gain access through SFTP to `/var/www/html/`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 year I had chance to answer to my own question. So if someone facing same problem they can follow this answer

There might be two simplest possible approach:

1. Assign all files & Folders owership to Webserver. In most case its `www-data` if apache/nginx is installed. If not find webserver user first [#Ref](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-osx-linux-find-apache-user/).

   `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/`

This will assign all files & folders ownership to `www-data` user & `www-data` user group. Check `chown` command [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chown-command-in-linux-with-examples/)

2. And add the FTP/SFTP username to webserver group.

   `sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu`

This will add `ubuntu` user to webserver group `www-data`. Check usermod command for [reference](https://careerkarma.com/blog/linux-add-user-to-group)`

3. Add permission to all files & folders

   `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www`

This will add permission to all files/folders in `/var/www/` as per follows

```
R = 4 (Octal Value for read permission)
W = 2 (Octal value for Write Permission)
X = 1 (Octal value for execute permission)

Owner: 4+2+1 = 7 (Read/Write/Execute)
Group: 4+2+1 = 7 (Read/Write/Execute)
Others: 4+1 = 5 (Read/Execute)
```

Through this way Owner & group has read, write and execute permissions. User logged in from ftp/sftp is already added on webserver group in second step. So Webserver & FTP user would both will be able add/edit files.

Comment: Cool but I consider it a bad idea to directly alter a website; the better approach would be to have each user log onto a separate partition and have a cron job create a timestamped backup of the files uploaded and then have the files moved to /var/www/ Next: chmod 777 is ALWAYS terrible. 750 is more than enough if you use "user"; if you use a "group" with diff users 770 is enough.

Comment: I agree with 777 & 750 permission. For access management ot would be better to use git and different branch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in as a user with sudo permission, or as root. If the user does not have root permission, they have to respect the folder owner

And since the owner is apache, of course certain non sudo users can't access it

Comment: I am able to logged in as root through putty by command `sudo su -`. But I logged into FTP account through `ubuntu` user

Comment: @PlanetHackers the user must be sudo, or the root user

Comment: I know that `sudo su -` do the same

Answer (score 0):

I manage with similar case in that way:

```sh
groupadd web
groupmems -g web -a myuser
chown -R .web /var/www/html/
chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/
mkdir ~myuser/web
mount --bind /var/www/html/ ~myuser/web
```

Explanation: create group for myuser (and others) and mount point in his mode directory. Then `mount --bind` apache dir.

You have to add `mount` to the start script.

Now you will have access to apache dir from your home.